# Limit amount of adding a certain Paragraph per Content type

Tags: 8, entities, paragraphs

I use Drupal 8 [Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) module.

I created a `Content type` Landingpage.

I create some Paragraph types like `Hero Image`, `Intro text` etc.

In the `Content type` Landingpage I created a Paragraph `Entity reference revisions` field. In the `REFERENCE TYPE`, the Paragraph types `Hero Image`, `Intro text` are selected.

How do I manage the site editor is able to only insert one time (one value), the `Hero Image` Paragraph type? Because it doesn't make sense to have more then one Hero image section on the website...

Answer (score 2):

Things which only should be unique to a node, should better be attached directly to that node.

There's already a [feature request](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs/issues/2499071) on DO. But I'd recommend you to solve this by attaching these things directly to the node, with standard image or text fields.

```
-- node type
  |__ hero image field
  |__ intro text field
  |__ paragraphs field
```

The only other alternative I see is to add multiple Paragraphs fields to your content type and then limit them to only one type and one item.

Answer (score 0):

Someone has since made a contrib module for this: [Paragraphs Limits](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs_limits)